# C - A line of code is changing the address of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, memory-address

I have a major issue that is happening to my code, that I've been trying to fix for hours now.

The code below is the one relevant to the issue that I am having...

The method addBucket:

```
void addBucket(SPACE * hashmap,char * tempvalue, char * tempkey){
    printf("BEGINNING OF FUNC...\n");

    void *prevadd = hashmap[0];
    char *value = varString(tempvalue);
    char *key = varString(tempkey);
    void *aftadd = hashmap[0];

    printf("BUCKET %s - %s\n",value,key);

    BUCKET *newBucket = malloc(sizeof(BUCKET *));
    fillBucket(value,key,newBucket);
    int hash = hashFunc(key);

    printf("FILL, FULFILLED\n");

    if(!hashmap[hash]){
        hashmap[hash] = malloc(sizeof(BASE*));
        hashmap[hash]->first = NULL;
    }

    ITEM *location;
    location = hashmap[hash]->first;

    //This creates a new item in the list, if there isn't any.
    //It does this by initialising the base, called box.
    if(!location){
        hashmap[hash]->first = (ITEM *) calloc(1,sizeof(ITEM *));
        hashmap[hash]->first->next = NULL;
        hashmap[hash]->first->prev = NULL;
        hashmap[hash]->first->data = newBucket;
    }

        //This instead adds a new item to the list.
    else{
        //This loop reaches the last ITEM in the linked list itself
        while(location->next){
            location = location->next;
        }

        //This initialises the newItem that will be added
        ITEM *newItem = (ITEM *) calloc(1,sizeof(ITEM));
        newItem->next = NULL;
        newItem->data = newBucket;
        newItem->prev = location;
        location->next = newItem;
    }
}
```

The declared structs that are used:

```
//Declares a struct called BUCKET.
//Serves as the bucket of the hash table.
typedef struct bucket{
    char * value; //The value inputted.
    char * key; //The key to be hashed.
}BUCKET;

//Declares a struct called ITEM.
//Holds the bucket, as well as the address to the next bucket.
//It also holds the address to the previous bucket.
typedef struct item{
    struct bucket * data;
    struct item * next;
    struct item * prev;
}ITEM;


//Declares a struct called BASE.
//Serves as the base node for the linked lists.
//The amount of initialised linked lists is the same as the amount of bases.
typedef struct base{
    struct item * first;
}BASE;

//Declares a struct of an array of BASES, meaning linked lists.
//Essentially defines the size of the hashspace.
typedef BASE *SPACE;
```

...And the method expandHashspace(); :

```
//Makes the size of the entire hashspace larger.
//Only takes a value larger than the current size due to possible data loss.
SPACE* expandHashspace(SPACE *hashmap, int newSize){
    if(newSize>100 || newSize<hashSpaceSize){
        printf("Exiting...\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        SPACE *nw = NULL;
        nw = realloc(hashmap, sizeof(SPACE *) * newSize);
        hashmap = nw;
        hashSpaceSize = newSize;
        return hashmap;
    }
}
```

Here's also the initHashmap() method:

```
SPACE* hashmapInit(SPACE *hashmap){
    hashmap = calloc(5, sizeof(SPACE *));
    hashSpaceSize = 5;
    return hashmap;
}
```

What I am doing here is initialising the hashmap, adding three buckets, expanding the hashmap, then adding three more buckets. Here's the order in more simple terms:

```
initHashmap();
addBucket(...); x3
expandHashmap();
addBucket(...); x3
```

However, on that last part, as soon as I run addBucket once, I get a SIGSEGV error. Checking through debugging, I realised something that was off.

Do you see the variables `*prevadd` and `*aftadd`? I added them while debugging to see what was happening to the address of hashmap[0]. Here is a picture of my results:

[image: Can you see the problem?]

As you can see there, the address of hashmap[0] varied wildly during those two `char *` lines. Specifically, the change of address happens on the `char *value` line.

Please go easy on me, as I've just started learning C 3 months ago, and I am still incredibly unaccustomed to memory allocation. If the error is obvious, please point it out, and if I have some problem with the way that I am allocating memory, or freeing it, I am more than happy to hear them (my code has a pretty major heisenbug that I cannot fix for the life of me, but that's beside the point).

Thank you in advance... Sorry for all the recent questions.

update : forgot to add varString();...

```
char* varString(const char *origString){
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0;origString[(int)i]!='\0';i++){}
    if(origString[i-1]=='\n') i-=2;
    char *newString = malloc(i);
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        newString[j] = origString[j];
    }
    newString[i+1] = '\0';
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: "Here is a picture of my results:" => only god know why you don't copy paste your debug info.

Comment: `realloc` may allocate the new block at a different address. It's impossible to tell whether you're handling this correctly without seeing the code that calls `expandHashspace`, which you haven't shown. Try reducing this to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: oh, I see you think `varString` is misbehaving and all the rest of that code dump may be irrelevant? Walk through `varString` and check it's working correctly, it looks weird to me. Should probably be using `strlen`/`strchr`/`strncpy` etc.

Comment: Your `varString` don't make anysense and have out of band problem.

Comment: @Stargateur - I'm using CLion, so I felt it was easier to show a picture. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Useless - I can try, although the code that calls expandHashspace is simply a switch statement from a menu.

Comment: @Useless - Also yes, that is what I am thinking is happening here, because varString seems to be causing problems. I might try avoiding varString altogether and see how it helps...

Comment: The **value** of `hashmap[0]` changed. Its address did not change. Variables cannot change their address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is not an answer, but it needed more formatting than would fit in a comment:*

Note that you are writing `"Value No. 1"`

Note the value of `aftadd` is `0x756c6156`

In memory, assuming a little-endian machine, the layout of the number in `aftadd` would be:

```
0x56 0x61 0x6c 0x75
```

In ASCII these would be:

```
'V' 'a' 'l' 'u'
```

Hint hint.

Comment: ...wait a second. Is it possible that the string is overwriting the hashmap[0]? I have no idea how that could be happening but that seems like the only possible answer. I had no clue to check the ASCII values of the value in aftadd... that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Yep, that happened to be the issue. Commenting out those lines and avoiding using the method altogether fixed the issue. Ironically your "not answer" was an answer!

Comment: looking at `varString`, the fact it overwrote `hashmap[0]` might indicate that the block `hashmap[0]` points to was freed at some point, making that block available to `malloc` again.  If you have `valgrind` it can identify these types of errors very handily.

Comment: I wish windows had a valgrind equivalent honestly. It sounds like a pain to have to boot back into ubuntu to use valgrind and debug code, but at this point I feel like it's my only alternative. I'm pretty sure I have a metric ton of memory leaks too, ain't too good with memory management heh.